# Implicit partial differentiation with polar co-ordinates

Tags: partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

We have been given $x=r\cos t$ and $y=r\sin t$ and asked to prove that $\partial^2t/\partial x^2+\partial^2t/\partial y^2=0$.

Assuming $r$ and $t$ to be dependent variables and $x$ and $y$ to be independent variables we proceed and obtain a relation containing $x, y$ and $t$ i.e $t=\arctan(y/x)$. Now we partially differentiate this w.r.t $x$ twice to obtain $\partial^2t/\partial x^2$. Similarly $\partial^2t/\partial y^2$ is also found out and then both the terms are added to reach the desired result.

Well and good till here.

But, a problem arises if we perform implicit partial differentiation on $\tan t=y/x$ to find $\partial^2t/\partial x^2$ and $\partial^2t/\partial y^2$. If this how we proceed then the two terms never add to be zero but instead give some non zero quantity. I get this:

$$\frac{\partial^2t}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2t}{\partial y^2}=-2\frac{\sin^3(t)}{r^2\cos(t)}+\frac{\tan(t)}{r^2}-2\frac{\sin(t)}{r}$$

My prof had told to separate out the dependent variable explicitly and then proceed with partial differentiation in case of polar co-ordinates but didn't actually tell us why. I thought he was saying so just because venturing otherwise would make stuff more cumbersome but after attempting this question it looks like I am missing a bigger picture.

P.S:- Please don't close the question just because formatting isn't proper. I don't know how to use latex and I am very sorry for that.

​
[image]

Comment: Using MathJax is not too hard. I've edited this for you

Comment: What did you try in your implicit partial differentiation? What was your result?

Comment: After writing everything in terms of r and t, i am getting (-2(sint)^3/(r^2)(cost))- (tant/r^2)-(2sint/r)

Comment: Thanks for editing :)

Comment: You’re welcome. You’re getting the expression you typed as $\partial^2t/\partial x^2+\partial^2t/\partial y^2$?

Comment: (-2(sint)^3/(r^2)(cost))- (tant/r^2)-(2sint/r) . This is what i am getting.

Comment: Is my edit correct?

Comment: Yes, this is what i am getting.

Comment: It would be very worth it to type up *how* you obtained that result. If you want, you can try to use `$\sin$` and `$\cos$` for trigonometry, and `$\partial$` for partial derivatives

Comment: I have incorporated a written solution in the form an image.